# Google Cloud Platform: VM creation - Console equivalent Gcloud command

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am creating a custom VM instance in Google Cloud using the Console (browser). There is an option to get the equivalent REST command but I would like to get an equivalent gcloud command so that I can create a new instance with exact same configuration from command line in the future. Can someone please point me out how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do all the steps in the console and you have the gcloud equivalent command at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I could not find it in the Notebook creation console but now I can find it in the VM creation page. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome @Vignesh ! so you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) : )